# How to get this timer to in a text adventure game? (py)

Tags: python, function, timer

So i'm making a text adventure game for my basics in computer science class, and I have this room where you gotta guess a number between 1 and 100 and you have 20 seconds otherwise you die, I can get the timer to say that it's started but once the timer hits 0 nothing happens. I have tried the timer code separately and it works just fine I'm probably just misunderstanding something basic about python most likely, here's part of the code sorry this is probably way to long

```
timer_1 = 20
random1 = random.randrange(1,100)

def random_number_1():
print("as you take the artifact you notice that under the artifact on the pedistool is a dial with the numbers    1-100 on it and below that is a engraving with the number 35 on it")
time.sleep(3)
print()
print(Fore.RED + "Water begins to fill the room and the opening to the artifacts room is suddenly blocked by a large pillar")
time.sleep(1.5)
print()
print(Fore.RED + "*QUICK GET THE DIAL TO THE CORRECT NUMBER TO STOP YOURSELF FROM DROWNING*")
timer()
guess = int(input(Fore.WHITE + 'Move the dial to a number between 1 and 100'))
if guess != random1:
 if guess < random1:
   print("The number was to small try moving the dial again ")
   guess = int(input('Move the dial to a number between 1 and 100'))
 if guess > random1:
   print("The number was to big try moving the dial again")
   guess = int(input('Move the dial to a number between 1 and 100'))
print('The dial clicks and the opening from whence you came opens, you run out as fast as possible as water rises from the depths of the artifacts chamber') 

def timer():
 print(Fore.RED + "timer has started")
 global timer_1
 if timer_1 != -1:
  time.sleep(1)
  timer_1 = (timer_1 - 1)
  if timer_1 == -1:
    pause()
    print(Fore.BLUE + 'you are dead')
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this exactly as you envision would require multithreading and the ability to interrupt the `input()` call (or using an alternative to `input()`, like the `keyboard` module, that you have more control over).

Rather than using an actual multithreaded timer, though, I'd suggest simply keeping track of the time and checking it after each `input()` call completes -- you won't be able to interrupt the user while they're typing, but after they hit Enter you'll be able to tell them whether they were fast enough or not.  Here's an example implementation that you can play with and try to incorporate into your own code:

```
import datetime
import random

deadline = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)
target = random.randrange(100)

print("Water begins to fill the room...")
print("Quick, get the dial to the correct number!")
while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Move the dial to a number between 1 and 100: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Butterfingers!")
        continue
    remaining = (deadline - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds()
    if remaining < 0:
        print("Too late!  You died!")
        break
    if guess < target:
        print("Too low!")
    elif guess > target:
        print("Too high!")
    else:
        print("You got it!")
        break
    print(f"{remaining:.0f} seconds left before you drown!")
```